# Where can I advertise a paper writing service targeting students?

Tags: advertising, writing

I have a client website that needs to be promoted and payment is done through the successful referrals I make. Which is the best platform to advertise and drive clients to the site?

Answer (score 1):

The best Advertising Platform Is "Google" , because now a days Google is the best platform for search queries, and many websites get highly organic traffic from it, so i suggest you to use "Google Adward tool" of Google for advertising. In which you have to just select the package and give necessary details of yours, than after that, Google will display your adds on their platforms, like they show your adds on search items etc.